# Is it possible to log traffic (responses in particular) on a domain using javascript?

Tags: javascript, post, client, traffic, interception

Is it possible to log HTTP responses on a domain using javascript? I know this is possible using the developer console, but I'm looking for a way to log the incoming traffic on a webpage with js only

Comment: Oh darn. I found a way to listen to websocket traffic that works but im not sure if it could be edited for my purposes

`WebSocket.prototype.send = new Proxy(WebSocket.prototype.send, { }}); `

Could this be repurposed for http traffic? using new Proxy()

Comment: Yes, using the [service worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).